# Weirds characters all over the screen Arch Linux

Tags: linux, display, arch-linux, gnome, gdm

Given that I have already searched everywhere without finding my same problem: I was watching a video from the browser, when unexpectedly some dots appeared on the screen and the characters of my browser appeared confused. After a couple of minutes the situation began to degenerate, also altering all characters:
[Thunderbird](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNiSN.png)

[Gnome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOLYR.jpg)

I have already checked if it was a video driver problem by installing the cuda. I checked if it was a font problem, but even changing it the problem persists. I have also tried to clear the OS cache and update and reboot the system several times. I also checked if it was a disk space problem, but it seems not.

[df -h](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArMS6.jpg)

I use Arch Linux as an operating system with gdm and Gnome as desktop environment. On grub this problem does not seem to persist, but only shows up at the gdm login screen.

These are the errors in the var log messages, but I don't think there is anything significant for my problem:

[log1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dciml.jpg)

[log2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXx2b.jpg)

Is there anyone who could kindly help me to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Your video card may be malfunctioning](https://www.google.com/search?q=graphics+memory+error+artifacts&tbm=isch).

Comment: It's not the graphic card because I've no problems with bios, grub and other tty. I have only problems with the display manager and with desktop environment. I think it could be a xorg problem.

Comment: It seems a driver problem with wayland, because with "only" xorg i can read normal characters; firefox and thunderbird are fixed with only xorg installed, but other applications doesn't work because there is some wayland's packages that are derived from gdm, sddm, gnome or plasma .

Comment: Maybe the problem is referred by this packages that I can't remove from the system (it can't boot without it): intel-ucode and libmfx.